# kendo-UI multiple panelbars

Tags: kendo-ui

I have 3 Panelbar and on at any point of time only one panelbar should be open.
How do i call/trigger collapse event of other PanelBars when one Panelbar is clicked.
for panelbar we have .Events(e=>e.Collapse("panelbar_collapse2")) but how do we call this event on click of another panelbar?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ExpandMode property of the PanelBar as

```
.ExpandMode(PanelBarExpandMode.Single)
```